# Trouble on setting the ':controller' parameter for a 'link_to' statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, controller

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to know why I get the error described below and how can I solve that.

In my `/views/articles/categories/_content.html.erb` file I have:

```
...
<%= link_to("New article", {:controller => content[:article_controller], :action => 'new'}) %>
...
```

If I set the `content[:article_controller]` to (both setting `true` and `false` for the `:only_path` option)

```
 1. content[:article_controller] = 'articles'
 2. content[:article_controller] = '/articles'
 3. content[:article_controller] = '/articles/'
 4. content[:article_controller] = '/'
 4. content[:article_controller] = ''
```

I get respectively the following errors (note `:controller` values):

```
 1. `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"articles/categories/articles", :action=>"new"})`
 2. `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"articles//articles", :action=>"new"})`
 3. `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"articles/", :action=>"new"})`
 4. `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"articles//", :action=>"new"})`
 4. `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"articles/categories/", :action=>"new"})`
```

**Is it a Ruby on Rails bug or is it my fault?** What is the problem and how can I solve that making the `link_to` properly work?

However I can solve that problem by using:

```
<%= link_to("New article", {:controller => '../', :action => 'new'}) %>
```

*But why it works with `'.../'` but not in other ways?*

---

I noticed that some time the controller path for which I try to set the `content[:article_contr8oller]` seems to relying on the "base" current controller path that is handling the view file (the controller file is `app/controllers/articles/categories/concerns_controller.rb` - read below for more information)... why it happens?

It also happens using `url_for`:

```
url_for(:controller => 'articles', :action => 'new')
```

Running the `rake routes` command I get the following:

```
   articles_categories GET    /articles/categories(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles/categories"}
                       POST   /articles/categories(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles/categories"}
 new_articles_category GET    /articles/categories/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles/categories"}
edit_articles_category GET    /articles/categories/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles/categories"}
     articles_category GET    /articles/categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles/categories"}
                       PUT    /articles/categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles/categories"}
                       DELETE /articles/categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles/categories"}
              articles GET    /articles(.:format)                     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}
                       POST   /articles(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"}
           new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles"}
          edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles"}
               article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}
                       PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles"}
                       DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles"}
```

P.S.: If you need more information, let me know and I will update the question as well.

---

**UPDATE I**

In my route file I have:

```
namespace :articles do articles :categories end

scope :path => 'articles/categories/:id', :controller => 'articles/categories/concerns' do
  ...
end

resources :articles
```

---

**UPDATE II**

In my view `/views/articles/categories/_content.html.erb` files I have:

```
<div class="links">
  <%= link_to("New article", {:controller => content[:article_controller], :action => 'new'}) %>
</div>
```

In my Articles::Categories::ConcernsController (that is, in the `app/controllers/articles/categories/concerns_controller.rb` file) I have:

```
def show
  @articles_category = Articles::Category.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      render :partial => '/views/articles/categories/_content.html.erb',
        :locals  => {
          :content => {
             :article_controller => '/articles'
          }
        }
        format.js  {
          ...
        end
  end
end
```

Comment: I still have no clue what you are actually trying to do here. Please show your full partial and full code that creates the content hash.

Comment: @Jeremy Weathers - I re-updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using symbols? I think they are more "direct".

```
<%= link_to("New article", {:controller => content[:article_controller].to_sym, :action => :new}) %>
```

Did you try using a relativ path?

```
<%= link_to("New article", {:controller => "../#{content[:article_controller]}", :action => 'new'}) %>
```

Comment: String or symbol it doesn't matter, nor does a relative path

Comment: @Koraktor - Using symbols I get the following error: 'ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert Symbol into Integer)'. Using relative paths I get the following error: 'ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"articles/../articles", :action=>"new"})'

Comment: @Backo, when using a url hash, the controller needs to be the name of the controller, not a path. The whole point of building the url from a hash (or preferably from a named route) is that you don't have to worry about relative paths.

Comment: @Jeremy Weathers - I set the name of the controller (not its path).

Comment: @Backo, neither of these examples from your question `'/articles/'` and comment `:controller=>"articles/../articles"` are controller names - both are paths. That is why they don't work. I have no idea why you have multiple controllers for creating new articles, but if that's what you are doing, then you either need to pass a valid controller name (e.g. 'articles' refers ArticlesController defined in app/controllers/articles_controller.rb), or build the root-relative URL manually. Again, it seems like you're fighting Rails here, but feel free to provide more complete explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using `link_to 'New article', new_article_path`? Why use the old, tired `url_for ...` when you can use the named path/url helper (`new_article_url`).

Comment: It is because I am passing some ':locals' variable to a partial template file.

Comment: You have more than one controller that manages articles? Why? I'm sensing some weird, possibly smelly code that you haven't shown.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but other controllers do not manages the Article class. Furthermore, the mentioned Category class is namespaced and it is just stated in routes before Article related routers. Can be it the problem? What information do you need to know (I wrote that in the question at *P.S.*)