# 'ActionView::Template::Error - No route matches' passing "old style" parameters for a 'link_to' statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, link-to

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I had this problem: [Trouble on setting the ':controller' parameter for a 'link_to' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868716/trouble-on-setting-the-controller-parameter-for-a-link-to-statement). No one answered with a solution but, trying and re-trying to find and solve the problem, I have found that on passing "old style" parameters (that is, using `controller` and `action` options instead of named route paths) sometime a `link_to` doesn't work as expected (that is, you get a `ActionView::Template::Error - No route matches` error although if you have controller and routes properly stated). Anyway you can set for that something like the following:

```
<%= link_to("New article", {:controller => '../', :action => 'new'}) %> # Note the "'../'"
```

and it works.

I would like to know **when** and **why**, in general, it happens: the `controller` option seems "forced" to refer to the relative or absolute path and not to the controller parameter you passed in.

That is, if I set `:controller => articles` and I use the above code in a view file managed by the `controllers/article/categories_controller.rb` I get the following error:

```
`ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"articles/categories/articles", :action=>"new"})`
```

because, as said above, the controller seems to refer to the `/articles/categories` path instead of `/articles` path (as it should be since, in this example, I set the controller to `articles`). Can be it a router problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "no route error " generally occurs when there is no proper route mentioned in routes.rb file.It has nothing to do with the absolute/relative path.